# Installation of clickme package

Tags: javascript, r

I want to use the clickme package for some data visualization and I need to install it.
I directly download the clickme.zip and decompress it in `D:\Public\Programme\R-3.0.3\library` and when I launch library(clickme)it works. But when I try it with an example like `clickme("points", 1:10)` it returned me an error message `Error: d3.v3.4.3.js not found at: D:/Public/Programme/R-3.0.3/library/clickme/templates/../shared_assets/d3.v3.4.3.js` ?
Can you explain me my mistake.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
> install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)
> library(clickme)
> clickme("points", 1:10)
Erreur : d3.v3.4.3.js not found at: D:/Public/Programme/R-3.0.3/library/clickme/templates/../shared_assets/d3.v3.4.3.js
```

EDIT 2:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rjson_0.2.13  stringr_0.6.2 knitr_1.6     yaml_2.1.11   clickme_0.5.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 evaluate_0.5.5  formatR_0.10    tools_3.0.3
```

Comment: you have not installed the package!, try this `install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)` and choose the zip file from the menu

Comment: thanks for your quick response! I did exactly what you said but it returned me the same error message !

Comment: did you get a messages after the `install.packages` statement, also show output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: The message appeared just when I launch the example, but install.packages("clickme") seems to work.

Comment: Well, **is** that  javascript file in the referenced location?  If not, I'd recommend deleting the `.../library/clickme` tree and reinstalling correctly.

Comment: Thank you all! I reinstalled it and it works nicely.